# I want to know the versions that I need to use to run a java selenium code

Tags: java, selenium

When I ran a simple java selenium code to start faceboook application, I am getting error "Timed out waiting for driver server to start."

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at newpackage.PractAuto.main(PractAuto.java:10)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:40026/status] to be available after 20002 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 10 more
```

My Code:

```
package newpackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class PractAuto {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/login/");
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("arunkumar3625@gmail.com");
          driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("Password");
          driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
          driver.findElement(By.name("mercurymessages")).click();
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='https://www.facebook.com/messages/conversation-8148306']")).click();

    }
```

Chrome browser is opening successfully but I'm getting the above error.

Comment: please share your code so we can tell where the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the latest version for selenium and the webdrivers through this link
https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Also, you can share your code for better understanding of the error reason.

After checking your code, you are setting the property of the driver to a wrong path. Property webdriver.chrome.driver should be the chrome driver not the chrome executable file.

Download it from that link: https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

Download latest chrome driver from https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and set property as :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","location of latest chrome driver")
```